# Getting POST parameter on symfony 2.2 and Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony

I am using Ajax.

And here is the Ajax-call part of my twig template,

```
$.post('{{path('acme_member_delScore')}}',               
    {data1: num }, //I assured that 'num' has right data in javascript
    function(response){
        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){//dummy check
          //do something
            console.log(response.id);
        }
}, "json");
```

And my routing.yml contains,

```
acme_member_delScore:
    pattern: /delScore
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeMemberBundle:Default:delScore}
```

While the action in my Controller is defined as follow,

```
public function delScoreAction()
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    $id = $request->query->get('data1');// but $id is null
 // ...
```

Do you have any idea why my $id variable (in delScoreAction) is always set to null?

Is there anything I have to check?

Comment: Btw. standard http ok response code is 200. But the check is not neccesary as the funtion is only called on success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$id = $request->request->get('data1');
```